# Determine number of elements of each type in a heterogeneous containercontainer

Tags: c#, .net

I use  Dictionary as a heterogeneous container:

```
Dictionary<string, Object> _Table;
```

It basically maps some description to int/double/string/ISerialiazable/etc types.

I want to efficiently calculate number of elements of each type, and then only print the elements of that type -- in SQL, I would  group by type, then print count and all elements for each type respectively.

I am not using LINQ, as I need to support this in .net 2.0.  I certianly encourage linq-like solutions for  educational purposes, but **please keep in mind that I will only use a code compatible with .NET 2.0**

I currently have a workaround, whereby I use Dictionaries for each types, and then iterate over all dictionaries.

Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: You wanted to print the objects as well:

```
Dictionary<Type, List<object>> numTypes = new Dictionary<Type, List<object>>();

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in _Table){
    Type type = object.GetType();
    if (!numTypes.ContainsKey(type)){
        numTypes[type] = new List<object>();
     }

        numTypes[type].Add(object);
}
```

Comment: second dictionary? looks like a redundancy.